# How can I update a google maps marker with user submitted information?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps

Sorry if this is somewhat lengthy but I've had this problem for a while now. So basically I've followed both of these tutorials 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/info-windows-to-db

These tutorials are for loading google map markers onto a canvas using google maps api and then also saving information about created markers from a user. I'm trying to essentially combine these 2 tutorials into something that allows me to load google map markers from a database (which I have done), and then allow a user to submit information about them from an infowindow which appears when a marker is clicked. The information that is submitted is to be updated in the marker's corresponding database row and then displayed when the marker is clicked. That part I'm having trouble on. I can't seem to get the marker's information in the database to update when the user hits the submit button in the infowindow. I'm trying to update the name of a quest that the user selects from a dropdown menu which appears in an infowindow upon clicking a marker.

I'll try to post only the code that's relevant to the problem. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

```
function initMap() {
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var mapOptions = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 12
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById('form')
});

messagewindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById('message')
});

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
        function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(content);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
}
//Loading in markers from DB via call.php
downloadUrl('call.php', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
        var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name'); //name of marker          
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
        var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address'); //address of marker
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
        var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
        var content = document.getElementById('form');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
}); //end of downloadurl
} //end of initmap


 function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
    }
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}
```

Here's the submit button's function

```
function saveData() {
if (document.getElementById("questType").value == "quest1") { //if quest1 is selected upon submission
    alert("1");
    var questTitle = "1";
}
var name = escape(document.getElementById('name').value);
var url = "phpsqlinfo_updaterow.php?name=" + name + "&questTitle=" + questTitle;
downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
        infowindow.close();
        messagewindow.open(map, marker);
    }
});
}
```

The previous 2 code blocks are most of my index.php

Here's my file where I attempt to update the database with the information submitted by the user. The only thing I'm trying to update is quest title.

```
<?php
require("phpsqlinfo_dbinfo.php");
include ("call.php");
$name = $_GET['name'];
$questTitle = $_GET['questTitle'];
$con=mysqli_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
 $db_selected = mysqli_select_db( $con, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}
$query = (("UPDATE markers SET questTitle ='$questTitle' WHERE name = '$name'"));
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 ?>
```

Finally, here is my call.php which outputs the xml doc to the browser

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
include('connect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    global $dom, $node, $parnode;
  // Add to XML document node
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id",$row['id']);
 $newnode>setAttribute("questTitle",$row['questTitle']);
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

It's been confusing for me on how to figure out how to tell which marker is being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `id` property to figure out which marker is being updated.

1) Create a global variable called `clickedMarker` which will contain the reference to the marker who's infowindow is opened and is being submitted.

```
var clickedMarker;
```

2)  While created the marker set the id property of the marker using the id retrieved from the database.

```
var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    id: id
});
```

3) When a marker is clicked and infowindow is opened set the marker as the clickedMarker

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    clickedMarker = marker;
});
```

4) While saving the data you can retrieve the id from the clickedMarker and send it to your php file as an additional query param.

```
function saveData() {
    if (document.getElementById("questType").value == "quest1") { //if quest1 is selected upon submission
        alert("1");
        var questTitle = "1";
    }

    var id = clickedMarker.id;
    var name = escape(document.getElementById('name').value);
    var url = "phpsqlinfo_updaterow.php?name=" + name + "&questTitle=" + questTitle + "&id=" + id;
    downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
            infowindow.close();
            messagewindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    });
}
```